# Have trouble concat indexing

Tags: dataframe, histogram, series, concatenation

I have been trying to put a series of values into a dataframe so later on can make a plot out of it. Here are my code:

```
datafileR = datafile = pd.read_csv("pixel_data.csv")
datafileR = pd.DataFrame(datafileR)
region = datafileR.groupby(["Reg"])

mm_MidEast= region["PP"].median().loc["Middle East and North Africa"] ##>> 138
mm_Africa= region["PP"].median().loc["Africa (excl MENA)"] ##>> 151
mm_Asia= region["PP"].median().loc["Asia and Pacific"] ##>> 158
mm_Europe= region["PP"].median().loc["Europe and Eurasia"] ##>> 127
mm_Cross= region["PP"].median().loc["Cross-regional"] ##>> 86

ppdata= pd.concat([mm_MidEast,mm_Africa,mm_Asia,mm_Europe,mm_Cross],axis="columns", sort=False)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs 
are valid
```

I understand what it means although do not know how to fix this problem by putting this series into as a DataFrame obj. This is the final graph I would like to achieve:

```
sns.set_theme()
display(ppdata["tip"].mean())
ax = sns.distplot(ppdata,color="black")
```

[expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1WJW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found a solution with a simple line of code:

```
sns.set_theme()
df2 = region["PP"].median() 
plt.bar(x=df2.index, height=df2.values, align="center",color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
```